# SPServices CAMLQuery is returning the ows ID with the value on lookup columns. How can I remove the ID from the results

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2013, caml, spservices

I work on a project that requires me to pull data from a SharePoint 2013 list and displays that data into html table.  All data is being queried and displayed, however two lookup columns are displaying an "ID;#".  How can I remove this from the front of the values, and just display the value ?

---

```
function get() {

    var method = "GetListItems";

    var webURL = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite();

    var list = "QA_DailyStatus";

    var fieldsToRead = "<ViewFields>" + "<FieldRef Name='ProjectRelease' />" + "<FieldRef Name='StastusDate' />" + "<FieldRef Name='ProductionReleaseDate' />" + "<FieldRef Name='Overall_QA_Status' />" + "<FieldRef Name='Overall_QA_Percent_Complete' />" + "</ViewFields>";

    var query = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Active_DSR' /><Value Type=\"bit\">1</Value></Eq></Where></Query>";



    $().SPServices

    ({

        operation: method,

        async: false,

        webURL: webURL,

        listName: list,

        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields Properties='True' />",

        CAMLQuery: query,

        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {

            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {

                var Release = $(this).attr("ows_ProjectRelease");

                var StatusDate = $(this).attr("ows_StastusDate");

                var ProductionDate = $(this).attr("ows_ProductionReleaseDate");

                var OverallStatus = $(this).attr("ows_Overall_QA_Status");

                var PercentComplete = $(this).attr("ows_Overall_QA_Percent_Complete");


                $("#myDataTable").append("<tr align='middle'>" +

                 "<td align='left'>" + Release + "</td>" +

                 "<td align='left'>" + StatusDate + "</td>" +

                 "<td align='left'>" + ProductionDate + "</td>" +

                 "<td align='left'>" + OverallStatus + "</td>" +

                 "<td align='left'>" + PercentComplete + "</td>" + "</tr>");

            });

        }

    });

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string manipulation. In the example below the substring starts at a specified character position and continues to the end of the string (removing the first n characters: in the given case - "ID:"):

```
$(this).attr("attribute name").substring(3);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!!!  Thank you.  I had assumed it was an issue with SharePoint, but this is a great solution for this.

Comment: How about if we have multiple look values can you please give me some idea